# Entity Framework IQueryable has no where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have these helper methods:

```
public static IQueryable<T> All<T>(this IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    where T : class
{
    return unitOfWork.Context.Set<T>();
}

public static T Find<T>(this IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    where T : class
{
    return unitOfWork.All<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

When I call the second one like this:

```
var payment = _unitOfWork.Find<ContactRow>
                          (p => p.PaymentAttemptRef == paymentAttemptRef 
                             && p.ContactType == type);
```

I expect the predicate to become part of the query!! but the problem is the select thats generated is without a where clause and pulls back all rows in the table.

Any idea why this is happening?  The second method calls the first, which returns an iqueryable so i thought that would do it no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your extension method to take an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` so that it can be converted to SQL.